# WPF Changing the style of a UserControl in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having issues setting the style of my UserContorl. I have the UserControl called BusyIndicator defined in a file. Below is the xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Client.UI.SVGs.BusyIndicator"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             >
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding Control.Visibility}">
                <Canvas Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"  Visibility="{TemplateBinding  Control.Visibility}">
                    <Path Fill="{Binding Foreground}"
                          Height="25"
                          Width="25"
                          Data="M20.519,4.617c-3.262-3.111-7.821-3.965-12.03-2.236 c-4.282,1.76-6.895,5.654-6.863,10.227l3.658-0.025C5.263,9.51,7.017,6.892,9.894,5.71c2.81-1.154,5.85-0.598,8.037,1.456 l-1.395,1.376h5.39V3.227L20.519,4.617z"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

I then reference the UserControl and use it in a ListView. The object the ListView is binding to has a property named Status. When Status is set to "Running", I'd like to change the style. When I run it, the Button is hidden so I know the Status property is notifying properly. But the svg:BusyIndicator control remains unchanged.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Views.Screens.CollectionResultsView"
                 AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CollectionResultsView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:svg="clr-namespace:Foo.Client.UI.SVGs;assembly=Foo.Client.UI" 
                 d:DesignWidth="700">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TargetStatusView}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>
                <TextBlock Text="X"></TextBlock>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Running">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
            <svg:BusyIndicator Width="25" Height="25">
                <svg:BusyIndicator.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="svg:BusyIndicator">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Running">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </UserControl.Style>
            </svg:BusyIndicator>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

I also tried to change the TargetType to UserControl but that didn't work either.

```
<svg:BusyIndicator Width="25" Height="25">
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Running">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</svg:BusyIndicator>
```

Setting `<svg:BusyIndicator Width="25" Height="25" Visibility="Hidden">` does work but if I add `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />` to the style, above `<Style.Triggers>`, it does not work.

I also tried other properties like `Opacity` and `Height` without success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does setting the visibility of the busyindicator work at all? Try to set the visibility directly to see if it works. I had an issue with a control that just didn´t react to the visibility property at all. If that´s the case, set the e.g. the height to 0 (which is a very dirty way to do it, I know -.-)

Comment: @Ben - Adding the visibility as an attribute to <svg:BusyIndicator> does hide it properly. But adding it as a style setter does not work. I tried setting the height but that didn't work either. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: If you can´t change the busy indicator itself for unknown reasons, how about wrapping the whole control into a panel (maybe a dockpanel) and make this trigger the visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way we defined the BusyIndicator control. Because `DataContext` was set to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. With this, when it was used in the ListView, the context was the control itself and not the data bound to the ListView. So `Binding="{Binding Status}"` did work because the BusyIndicator usercontrol doesn't have a Status prooperty.

We updated the control below and it worked.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Client.UI.SVGs.BusyIndicator"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Foreground}" 
                          Data="M20.519,4.617c-3.262-3.111-7.821-3.965-12.03-2.236 c-4.282,1.76-6.895,5.654-6.863,10.227l3.658-0.025C5.263,9.51,7.017,6.892,9.894,5.71c2.81-1.154,5.85-0.598,8.037,1.456 l-1.395,1.376h5.39V3.227L20.519,4.617z">
                </Path>
                <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Foreground}" Data="M4.733,20.634c3.26,3.111,7.82,3.964,12.03,2.234c4.281-1.76,6.894-5.652,6.862-10.227l-3.658,0.025c0.021,3.073-1.733,5.69-4.61,6.872c-2.808,1.155-5.85,0.598-8.037-1.457l1.396-1.375H3.324v5.315L4.733,20.634z" >
                </Path>
    </Canvas>       
</UserControl>
```